# v-model on input does not dynamically change when passed in a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

I don't know where it went wrong in here.

gets the desired number of textarea

```
<input type="number" min="0" v-model="columnNum">
<button @click="addTextArea(columnNum)">ok</button>
```

then push it to an array inside another array

```
addTextArea(a){
 var colArray = [];
        for(var i=1; i<=a; i++){ 
          colArray.push({col_num : i , description : "edit me"})
        }
        this.all.col = colArray;

    },
```

and display it like this

```
<textarea v-for="textareaCol in all.col" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="textareaCol.description"></textarea>
```

it doesnt work the first time you click 'ok', but if you try to input another value after you click 'ok', it triggers the function and run it. it seems that its not passing the value when it triggers the *addTextArea* function

Comment: Instead of `this.all.col = colArray`, try `this.$set(this.all, 'col', colArray)`. I think it might be a reactivity issue. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: You're missing `:key` on the `<textarea>`

Comment: I tried, still got the same result. but it worked when I created `all:{ col:"" }` it works just fine. and now I have the same logic in a different component. my remedy doesn't work with this one. I still have no idea why.

Comment: `all: { col: '' }` will need to exist in order for Vue to "know" to track that property / reference. That's why it's required but as that part of the code was omitted from your question, we wouldn't have guessed that.

Comment: i only have `all:{}` it worked though, and as I have read in [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) vue allows it. my question really is, why is the function not triggering when clicked but then when trying to input a new value after clicking the button it triggers it. just something i dont understand, anyway thanks for answering :)